# States in Ember.js without using routes?

Tags: routes, ember.js, statechart

I am trying to understand whether States in Ember.js are only designed/assumed to be defined in a route manager, and whether routes are integral to Ember. Pretty much all of the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/) I've seen seem to assume you want states and routes exactly matching.

I want to create states that are not dependent on routes, but just on the state of the application. For example, in an email client, I might have a state "userHasSpecifiedRecipient." Only if this state is true might I enable the message box of the form. But obviously I don't want the url to be:

`myEmailClient.com#composingMessage_userHasSpecifiedRecipient_userIs...` etc.

Are there examples of this?

Second question: Can I mix states that are coupled with routes and states that are not?

Finally: I saw some advice that recommended people use Ember's [sproutcore-statechart](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-statechart) addon if they want things like concurrent states. Is this still true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In EmberJS, there is an implementation of a [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine), Ember.StateManager. The StateManager uses Ember.State to represent states in the state machine, which have `enter` and `exit` functions, etc. Have a look at [Class: Ember.StateManager](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.StateManager&src=false).

For an example that uses the StateManager, the Ember.View uses it to manage the different states of a View. Another example is Ember-Data, which uses a state manager to track the different states a record can have.

In order to make life easier and avoid boilerplate code, there is a `Router` implementation in the latest version of EmberJS, which is still very much a work-in-progress, with updates once or twice a week. You can find the latest on the [GitHub downloads](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/downloads).

`Ember.Router` is the subclass of `Ember.StateManager` responsible for providing URL-based application state detection. The `Ember.Router` instance of an application detects the browser URL at application load time and attempts to match it to a specific application state. Additionally the router will update the URL to reflect an application's state changes over time. ([JSDoc in Ember source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/router.js))

Additionally, because the `Ember.Router` extends `Ember.StateManager` and `Ember.Route` extends `Ember.State`, these are interchangeable. In fact, just a day a go more support was made to support the mixture of states and routes, see [Support basic States inside of Routes](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/8fd57b354c0e46f2f732a1ff1d75a078200a6fb1).

Answer (score 2):

You can change the routers location implementation to 'none' to disable this features. other methods are 'hash' or 'history' (with the current ember-latest.js on github).

https://github.com/joliss/ember.js/blob/50aff86ef5b6847108bc8c32364171815c230d36/packages/ember-application/lib/system/location.js

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    location : Ember.Location.create({
        implementation : 'none'
    })
});
```

Comment: I also just found a fairly recent [example by Yehuda](https://gist.github.com/2679013) that uses Ember.StateManager instead of Ember.Router. The latter is what the documentation uses. What's the difference between them?

Comment: Also, as to my second question above, what if I want to have some subset of states that are coupled to routes? In that case I wouldn't want location disabled entirely. (If this mixing is hard, though, it's not so important and I can implement routes some other way.)

Comment: Oh, or should I maybe have two different StateManagers, one with locations and one without?

Comment: The state-manager/route-manager API seems to be very much a moving target in recent weeks. Unless you can produce a working jsfiddle for a given example, assume any examples from Yehuda describe works-in-progress that have most likely been broken by later work.

Comment: @SamFen This gist is deprecated. Three or four weeks ago, they definitely move the Router feature separated from StateManager.(see the Mixin routable) The Ember.Router IS an Ember.StateManager + Ember.Routable. To answer your question, they use Ember.StateManager in the DS.Model class (see ember-data)